# Splitting string by set amount, and assigning variables to the splits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, slice

I have the string "hello123", and would like to split it into "hell" and "o123", however I dont know how. Also, I would like to assign `firstPart` to equal "hell" and `secondPart` to equal "o123". Any help is much appreciated.

```
Here is my code:
var firstPart;
var secondPart;
var str = "hello123"
alert(str.split(""));
```

Comment: @igetstuckalot Do you have any pattern on splitting the source string?

Comment: i dont know what you mean. I want to split them into strings of 4 characters, if thats what you men.

Comment: `alert(str.match(/.{4}/g));`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'hello123';
var firstPart=str.substr(0,str.length/2);
var secondPart=str.substr(str.length/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "hello123";
var firstPart = str.substr(4); // => "Tabs1"
var secondPart = str.substr(id.length - 4); // => "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this, to use the window object for this.

```js
var str = 'hello123';

str.match(/.{4}/g).forEach(function (a) {
    window[a] = a;
});

document.write(hell + o123);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'hello12312312bhfbdhfbh13h123bkbkfbk123bk123bk213kj';

document.write(str.match(/.{4}/g));
```